# segmentation fault on chars array

Tags: c, string, algorithm, segmentation-fault

I need to count how many strings there is in a "string list". Each string ends as usual with a NUL char (`'\0'`), and the list ends with two NUL chars in succession.

I wrote a function but I keep getting a segmentation fault:

```
int numStrsInList(const char* strList) {
    int count = 0;
    int flag = 0;
    if(!(*strList))
        return -1;

    while (flag != 2) {
        if (!(*strList)) {
            count++;
            flag++;
        }
        else
            flag = 0;
        strList++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

for example:

```
const char* empty = "\0";
const char* one = "Hell0 \t\n\v\f\rw0r1d\0";
const char* two = "Hello\0 \t\0";
const char* simple = "Hello\0world\0!\0";
```

the invocation for example:

```
numStrsInList(empty)
numStrsInList(one)
numStrsInList(two)
numStrsInList(simple)
```

for this strings the output should be:

```
0
1
2
3
```

Comment: because you are passing something bad to this function (or even not to this one...)

Comment: Your function is of limited significance by itself.  We ordinarily expect you to provide a [mcve].  Also, do not present code with line numbers.

Comment: whats a `/0` that you are referring to? That's not the right way to use it if you are indeed putting this into the string... it should be `\0` as a FYI. USe a debugger, and step through the code and figure it out.

Comment: Won't your function count too many strings, by incrementing `flag` when the two `\0` characters that terminate the list of strings are read?

Comment: Where are lines 1 to 34? Aside: if the function works, `count` will be 1 too many, or 2 too many, as it is unclear how the list ends. Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. Show the input, the expected output, and the actual output as text *in the question*.

Comment: It always adds a '\0' in the end of a chars array. so there are 2 consecutive zeros.

Comment: `if(!(*strList)) return -1;` makes no sense. Maybe you meant `if(!strList) return -1;` (i.e. check for `numStrsInList(NULL)`)? Aside from that and the aforementioned off-by-one error in the result, your function is fine. You must be passing in a NULL (which would be caught by the change I proposed) or a string that doesn't match the expected format (about which nothing can be done inside the function).

Comment: Having pasted your incomplete code into a program, I get the output `-1 2 3 4`. So from comments about counting one too many, I guess the first input is causing your crash somehow.

Comment: The code you've presented, run with the inputs you added, produces no error for me.  I get the same output as WeatherVane.  Valgrind indicates no out-of-bounds memory accesses such as I would expect to see associated with a segmentation fault.  I repeat, if you want help, present a [mcve].

Comment: @Weather Vane, Re "*I guess the first input is causing your crash somehow.*", No, nothing about the first input would cause a SEGFAULT. The OP's specifically returns -1 if the first string is empty. Of course, that's probably not what they meant to do, but that's already been mentioned.

Comment: @John Bollinger, Re "*produces no error for me*", Well, it produces the wrong output, but it doesn't segfault.

Comment: How the hell do you know which `'\0'` is the last `'\0'` in the list? If you can't definitively tell what the end of the *"list"* is, you will just go ripping off into *Undefined Behavior*" after the end of your list leading to your *Segmentation Fault*.

Comment: @ikegami, "produces no error for me" should be interpreted in the context of the question, which asks specifically about a segfault.

Comment: @David C. Rankin, Re "*How the hell do you know which '\0' is the last '\0' in the list?*", If the previous character was also a `\0`.

Comment: @ikegami take a coffee break, please.

Comment: @John Bollinger, You are mistaken. The OP said the output should be `0 1 2 3`. Didn't you get `-1 2 3 4`? That's definitely an error!

Comment: If you are looking for a hardstop of `2` and you have `"my\0"`, then you are reading beyond the end of your list.

Comment: @ikegami because you are attacking the commenters who are trying to help a badly presented question.

Comment: @David C. Rankin, `"my\0"` creates a 4-byte block, the last two of which are `0`.

Comment: OP, you need to supply length of the entire array to the function, otherwise your code might go out of boundaries.

Comment: @0andriy, No, a sentinel value approach such as the one used by the OP is perfectly fine alternative to providing the length.

Comment: @ikegami where the train is falling off the track is the fact that `strList` is passed as `char *` not `char **`. With every non *nul-byte* contained, `flag` is reset to `0` and the loop keeps spinning away. (am I wrong on that? -- I could need more coffee...)

Comment: @ikegami, just take a coffee break, indeed. Function like that is error prone UB generator.

Comment: @David C. Rankin, [How it works](https://pastebin.com/SCPEd3gG)

Comment: @0andriy, That's like saying "`strlen` is error prone UB generator". Yes, if you provide garbage to `strlen` or `numStrsInList`, you'll get UB. Doesn't mean one shouldn't use `strlen` or `numStrsInList`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, no the function more or less implements the spec as given.  Arrays of `char` can contain internal null bytes, which the problem presumes will be the case.  The example inputs are appropriate for the problem characterization given, and do not result in the function running off the end of the array.

Comment: @ikegami - yep, I do need more coffee and I stand corrected. Thank you.

Comment: @ikegami, it exactly means that. You can't use `str*()` helpers here as is.

Comment: @0andriy, [You can](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44640507/1)

Comment: Sheesh... where my train fell off the track is missing the *sentinel* double-nul-byte created by virtue of defining the *string literals* with an embedded nul-byte at the end which by definition of what a string literal is causes the 2nd to be added -- duh.... In that case just `return 0` in the first test and `count -1` thereafter. I apologize for my denseness -- happens...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, it's still error prone. If function gets garbage on input -> UB is a question of time.

Comment: Agreed... talk about a forest-for-the-trees issue. That is a whacky way to define a list object that would be damn near impossible to guarantee as input and even more trouble to create in normal operations unless you had a preliminary function where you did pass the overall length and whose purpose was to slap another *nul-byte* on the end of the string before passing it to this count function -- not sure I see the usefulness outside some particular special case setting....

Answer (score 4):

There are several issues with your code....

```
int numStrsInList(const char* strList) {
    int count = 0;
    int flag = 0;
    if(!(*strList))      // this is not right, numStrsInList("\0") returns -1 instead of 0
        return -1;       // did you mean if (!strlist) ??

    while (flag != 2) {
        if (!(*strList)) {    // maybe using this notation if (!strlist[0]) 
            count++;          // would help in avoiding the error above
            flag++;           // c library has strlen() functions
        }                     // that are much faster and will make your code more readable
        else
            flag = 0;
        strList++;
      }
      return count;
    }

  }
```

Compare to, overall length added per request :)

```
int numStrsInList(const char* strList, int maxlen) 
{
   // returns the number of strings in a null terminated array of 
   // contiguous null-terminated strings.
   // maxlen is the maximum overall length of the buffer, 
   // can be 0 to defeat length checking

   const char* s;
   int result = 0;

   if (!strList) return -1;

   for (s = strlist; 
        s > (char*)1 && s[0] != 0; 
        s = (maxlen) ? (memchr(s, 0, maxlen - (s - strlist)) + 1)
                     : (s + strlen(s) + 1) )
   {
     if ((s - strlist) > maxlen) return -1;
     ++result;
   }

   return result;
}
```

Comment: Without overall length your code might go out of boundaries.

Comment: Yup.  Garbage in garbage out, as they say.

Comment: Yep, now looks like it seems it should look (the problematic `strlen()` still present, though).

Comment: Maybe I"m just dense today, but I see the issue as "Without passing the number of strings contained in `strList` (and `strList` being empty)", you will always be checking beyond the end of `strList` unless it is terminated with a *sentinel* `"\0\0"`

Comment: There is no way to totally avoid segmentation faults, looping through each char will not prevent that either,  This function provides best effort.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy, you just need to check each byte for `\0` without using `str*()` helpers. And thus on each iteration you compare your current length to a maximum.

Comment: That's proven to be slower than using strlen.   strlen uses repnz, or faster.

Comment: You may use aligned access on machines that allows you to do so. On x86_64 you can check by 8 bytes at once without getting a page fault.

Comment: That's exactly what strlen does.  It may still generate a page fault.

Comment: Nope, if your maximum length doesn't jump to the next page you are fine.

Comment: Page faults may occur on 4k byte boundary on x86/x64.  That's the size of the pages.  strlen is written in assembler, and makes use all possible tricks to get the length as fast as possible,

Comment: @ikegami  ??  zero length strings are checked by the `s[0] != 0` statement, from the very first string on...

Comment: @0andriy  even going though the bytes 1 by 1 and checking for 4k-byte boundary can generate a segmentation fault.  **There is no cheap and  effective way to prevent segmentation faults due to strings non ended properly.**  If there was, you would find it on every example on SO.

Comment: How?! In properly designed function you do first check for limit, after that you access the next elements.

Comment: There is quite a readability hit, though, but you are right.

Comment: fixed that...  did I mention... I was getting... what I shouldn't mention:)

Answer (score 2):

Just use standard C function `strchr` declared in the header `<string.h>`.

For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

size_t numStrsInList(const char *s)
{
    size_t n = 0;

    if (!(s[0] == '\0' && s[1] == '\0'))
    {
        do
        {
            s = strchr(s, '\0');
            ++n;
        } while (*++s);
    }

    return n;
}

int main( void )
{
    printf("The number of substrings is %zu\n", numStrsInList("\0"));
    printf("The number of substrings is %zu\n", numStrsInList("Hell0 \t\n\v\f\rw0r1d\0")) ;
    printf("The number of substrings is %zu\n", numStrsInList("Hello\0 \t\0"));
    printf("The number of substrings is %zu\n", numStrsInList("Hello\0world\0!\0"));
}
```

The program output is

```
The number of substrings is 0
The number of substrings is 1
The number of substrings is 2
The number of substrings is 3
```

Without using the standard function `strchr` the function can be implemented the following way

```
size_t numStrsInList(const char *s)
{
    size_t n = 0;

    if (!(s[0] == '\0' && s[1] == '\0'))
    {
        do
        {
            while (*s) ++s;
            ++n;
        } while (*++s);
    }

    return n;
}
```

Take into account that for example this string

```
"\0A\0"
```

contains two substrings: `""` and `"A"`. While this string `"\0"` contains neither substring.
As for your code then already this statement

```
if(!(*strList))
    return -1;
```

does not make sense.

It seems you mean

```
if(!strList)
    return -1;
```

that is that the pointer `strList` is not equal to `NULL`. However by analogy with standard string functions it is better when the caller checks whether the pointer is equal to `NULL`.

Comment: Same issue. It might go to UB.

Comment: @0andriy Please provide an example of valid input that causes UB.

Comment: @chux, isn't obvious? Any non-null terminated garbage which steps over page size will generate a page fault. Depending on what the page is next you might have many surprises up to segmentation fault.

Comment: @0andriy Your example does not meet OP's criteria of "Each string ends as usual with a NUL char ('\0'), and the list ends with two NUL chars in succession.".  [GIGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out)

Comment: @0andriy You can generate undefined behavior by just passing a NULL pointer to a C standard string function. And what? Are you suggesting to rewrite all C standard string functions?:) You can write such a proposal to the C Standard Committee.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, Don't divide to black and white, please. And no, I'm talking about something else. The requirements to the function are suck (even if you avoid UB cases).

Comment: @0andriy Nothing prevents you to generate undefined behavior if you want to generate it. So your comments do not make sense.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, see above answer. The guy got what I was telling him and did almost working solution (some typos still). Your code is a UB generator. Production ready code should have neither confusing requirements, no error prone behaviour.

Comment: @0andriy He made a mistake listening you. One more if you can not understand even now. Suggest the C Standard Committee to redefine for example the standard function strlen because it can generate undefined behavior. What is the problem?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, as I said, just good luck with your error prone excerpt.

Comment: @0andriy And what about strlen? Do you have already sent your proposal to the C Standard Committee?:)